# Plural for math notations

Tags: grammatical-number, mathematics

I have a question about the usage of plural in mathematics in the following context.

> Suppose we have functions *f*<sub>1</sub>, *f*<sub>2</sub>, ⋯.

Which of these sentences is correct (if any)?

1. Among the functions *f*<sub>i</sub>'s there is no repetition.
2. Among the functions *f*<sub>i</sub> there is no repetition.
3. Among the functions *f*<sub>i</sub>'s there are no repetitions.
4. Among the functions *f*<sub>i</sub> there are no repetitions.

The focus is on whether I should use 's or not. Also, is or are.

Comment: People may downvote this question since it is about a mathematical convention and not standard English, but I have given my opinion below.

Comment: I hope it is not down-voted, because it is a good example of proper use of mathematics in English, and so often the two seem to clash.

Answer (score 7):

You can think of "f<sub>i</sub>" as shorthand for the list of individual functions "f<sub>1</sub>, f<sub>2</sub>, ..., f<sub>n</sub>, ..." Understood as such, the correct sentence would be:

> Among the functions f<sub>i</sub> there are no repetitions.

This would be a shorthand for:

> Among the functions f<sub>1</sub>, f<sub>2</sub>, ..., f<sub>n</sub>, ... there are no repetitions.

Notice the plural "function*s*" and the use of the plural verb "are".

---

Alternatively (and maybe less standardly), you could think of "f<sub>i</sub>" as a kind of count noun which applies to every function in the list. Understood as such, the correct sentence would be:

> Among the f<sub>i</sub>'s there are no repetitions.

Normally, you would *not* use an apostrophe in a pluralization. But you can get away with using the apostrophe here (even though it is not indicating possession), just like you can get away with using it to make a pluralization for something like a letter, as in:

> There are two *a*'s in the word *actual*.

The apostrophe is needed to forestall confusion.

---

I don't think there is hard and fast rule about which is the right way to view the mathematical convention of using "f<sub>i</sub>". Your best bet is to pick one way of understanding it and stick to it. Or else forget about it entirely and just say:

> Among the functions there are no repetitions.

After all, why muddy the page with needless formalism?

Comment: I find the use of "the fi's" jarring and recommend against it. But I'm upvoting because everything else in this answer is excellent advice.